# Google Conversion tracking - what can be the cause of 400 error?

Tags: google-tag-manager, drupal-8

I've integrated Google Tag Manager and both GTM and Google Analytics work just fine, however I have a problem with conversion tracking:
[image: Google conversion tracking error]

After many hours of debugging I think it might be caused by consent and I try to integrate requirejs & GTM api to my Drupal website. Am I thinking correctly? URL seems to be fine and it was working before Google changed the consent politics.